# Recargar un div con JavaScript en un html con extends de Python con Flask

Tags: javascript, python, flask

Estoy usando Python con Flask para el funcionamiento de una pagina web, ahora necesito recargar parte de la pagina al pulsar un boton.
El problema es que al recargar solo esa parte pierdo cabecera, estilos ... que vienen de un extedns de Flask.
Solo funciona al recargar la pagina completamente con "location.reload()".

base.html (por si hace falta verla, pinta la cabecera, footer e importa los css)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=”es”>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./../static/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./../static/css/base.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./../static/css/style-{% block style %} {% endblock %}.css">
    <link  rel="icon"   href="./../static/img/burger-y.png" type="image/png" />
    <meta charset=”UTF-8″ />
    <title>Restaurante</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header class="p-3 text-bg-dark">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="d-flex flex-wrap align-items-center justify-content-center justify-content-lg-start">
            <a href="/" class="d-flex align-items-center mb-2 mb-lg-0 text-white text-decoration-none">
              <svg class="bi me-2" width="40" height="32" role="img" aria-label="Bootstrap"><use xlink:href="#bootstrap"/></svg>
            </a>
    
            <ul class="nav col-12 col-lg-auto me-lg-auto mb-2 justify-content-center mb-md-0">
              <a  href="/" target="_parent" class=""><img class="nav-link px-2 header-icon" src="./../static/img/burger-y.png"></a>
              <!--<li><a href="{{ url_for( 'index' ) }}" class="nav-link px-2 text-secondary">Home</a></li>-->
              <li><a href="/carta" target="_parent" class="nav-link px-2 text-white">Carta</a></li>
              <li><a href="/locales" target="_parent" class="nav-link px-2 text-white">Locales</a></li>
              <li><a href="/faqs" target="_parent" class="nav-link px-2 text-white">FAQs</a></li>
              <li><a href="/carrito" target="_parent" class="nav-link px-2 text-white">Pedido</a></li>
            </ul>
    

            <div class="text-end">
              {% if current_user.is_authenticated: %}
                <a class="btn btn-outline-light me-2" href="/user">{{ current_user.nombre }}</a>
                <a class="btn btn-danger" href="/logout">Logout</a>
              {% else: %}
                <a href="/login" class="btn btn-outline-light me-2">Login</a>
                <a href="/register" class="btn btn-success">Sign-up</a>
              {% endif %}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </header>


      <div>
        {% block content %} {% endblock %}
      </div>



      <footer class="footer">
        <p class="col-md-4 mb-0 text-muted">&copy; 2022 Company, Inc</p>
        <a href="/" target="_parent"><img class="footer-icon" src="./../static/img/burger-y.png"></a>
        <p class="nav col-md-4 justify-content-end">Todos los derechos reservados</p>
    </footer>

</body>
</html>
```

carrito.html

```html
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block style %}carrito{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
    <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename= 'js/carrito.js') }}"></script>
    <div class="container separar" id="carritoRecargar">
        <div class="carrito-general">
            <p>Vista General</p>
            <script>
                carritoTotal()
            </script>
        </div>
        <div class="carrito-tarjetas">
            <script>
                renderCarrito()
            </script>
        </div>
        
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

carrito.js

```javascript
function renderCarrito(){
    carrito = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("carrito"))
    var template = []
    let id = 0;

    carrito.map(item => {
        precio = item.price.substring(0, item.price.length - 1)
        var productPrice = precio * item.cant
        template.push(
            '<div class="carrito-tarjeta">' +
            '<img class="carrito-tarjeta_img" src=' + item.img + '>' +
            '<p class="carrito-tarjeta_nombre" id = name-' + id + '>' + item.name + '</p>' +
            '<input class="carrito-tarjeta_cant" id = cant-' + id + ' type="number" min="1" onchange="cantItem(' + id +')" value="' + item.cant + '">' +
            '<p class="carrito-tarjeta_precio">' + (productPrice).toFixed(2) + ' €</p>' +
            '<button class="btn btn-danger carrito-tarjeta_eliminar" onclick="deleteItem(' + id +')">x</button>' +
            '</div>'
        )
        id++
    })
    var htmlString = template.join('')
    document.write(htmlString)
}

function deleteItem(id){
    const itemName = document.getElementById('name-'+id).textContent
    carrito = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("carrito"))
    const newCarrito = carrito.filter(item => item.name != itemName)
    localStorage.setItem("carrito", JSON.stringify(newCarrito))
    location.reload()
}
```

A ver si alguien puede ayudarme para poder resolver la tarea ya que he probado varias opciones y ninguna me da resultado, recarga sin clases ni cabecera, o una pagina dentro de otra, renderiza vacio y no encuentro la forma de conseguirlo.
Seguire intentandolo y si se necesita mas informacion no duden en preguntarme, gracias